# Python class variable list vs int inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, class

While working on a piece of code today I've found this somewhat surprising behavior and I'm looking for an explanation. See the following piece of code and output it produces

```py
class Test:
    t1 = []
    t2 = 1

    def xyz(self):
        self.t1 += [1]
        self.t2 += 1


for i in range(10):
    v = Test()
    v.xyz()
    print(v.t1)
    print(v.t2)
```

Output

```
[1]
2
[1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
```

My question is why it's somewhat inconsistent? It seems like `t2` (int) gets reinitialized every time. On the other hand `t1` (list) doesn't. According to documentation I'd assume `t2` isn't reinitialized every time and should just be increased. Class properies should be shared among the instances of objects. What's exactly going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.attr` modifies the *instance* variable `attr`. You want a `classmethod` to modify class level attrs:

```py
class MyClass:
    a = 0
    
    @classmethod
    def inc(cls):
        cls.a += 1


for i in range(4):
    c = MyClass()
    c.inc()

print(c.a)
4
```

### Why does the list work, though?

Because the list is a reference to `cls.t1`, and the in-place addition modifies the reference. This is not the case with ints, where `__iadd__` or `+=` still returns a new int:

```py
l1 = []

l2 = l1

l2 += ['HI']

l1
['HI']

a = 2
b = a # b and a point to 2

b += 1 # creates a new int, 3, and assigns to the name b

a # a is the same
2

b
3
```

The same is happening with your class:

```py
class MyClass:
    v1 = []

    def f(self):
        self.v1 += [1] # self.v1 is another name pointing to the same list as v1 in the class def
```

So the modification propagates. Using `@classmethod` modifies `cls.v1`, which *is* `class MyClass: v1=[]`. It's not another name for it, it *is* the class-level variable `v1`.

Comment: Is my understanding correct, that inplace addition happens with lists, because they are mutable, and doesn't happen with ints because they are immutable (thus creating new pointer)?

Comment: Sort of. There isn't really the concept of a pointer here, it's really how the `__iadd__` (shorthand `+=`) works with these objects, and how names and values work. [This blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is a really good one on the topic